# wxpython flexgridSizer button bottom right corner

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, wxwidgets

I would like to put the "Enregistrer" button to the bottom right corner:
[image]

Here is my code :

```
    sizer = wx.FlexGridSizer(10, 6, 10, 10)
    # here i had all the other stuff an put it in the sizer
    # self refere to  a wx.panel
    # SPACE
    for v in range(0, 40):
        sizer.Add(10,10,wx.EXPAND)

    btn = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, "Enregistrer")
    btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.save)
    sizer.Add(btn, 2, wx.ALIGN_BOTTOM|wx.ALIGN_RIGHT)
    self.SetSizer(sizer)
```

I can't fiqure it out why the button dosen't goes to the corner.

Can you please help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mismatch between the declared size of you `FlexGridSizer` (10x6) and the number of items that you are putting in it (40 + 1 button).
Changing your code a tad:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import wx
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, ID, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, ID, title, wx.DefaultPosition)
        sizer = wx.FlexGridSizer(10, 6, 10, 10)
    # here i had all the other stuff an put it in the sizer
    # self refere to  a wx.panel
    # SPACE
        v=[]
        for i in range(0,59):
            v.append(wx.StaticText(self,-1,"......"+str(i)))
        for i in v:
            sizer.Add(i,1,wx.EXPAND)

        btn = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, "Enregistrer")
        #btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.save)
        sizer.Add(btn,0,wx.EXPAND|wx.ALIGN_RIGHT)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame = MyFrame(None, -1, "FlexGridSizer")
        frame.Show(True)
        self.SetTopWindow(frame)
        return True
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp(0)
    app.MainLoop()
```

We get this:
[image]

If, however, you want the button separately in the far right-hand bottom of the screen, you might want to add more than one sizer or choose a different sizer altogether. Such as a `GridSizer` or a `GridBagSizer`